# Different order of adding same type objects causes an error

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Could anyone explain why adding three objects like this `a+(a+a)` causes problems while `a+a+a` and `(a+a)+a` does not? The `Foo` class has one attribute `num`. Adding two `Foo` objects returns one with sum of their `num` values. Here is my code.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Foo.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Foo a(4), b;
    b = a + a + a; // works fine
    cout << a.getNum() << " " << b.getNum() << endl; // outputs "4 12" as it should
    b = a + (a + a); // this one causes an error
    cout << a.getNum() << " " << b.getNum() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Foo.h

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H


class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo();
        Foo(int a);
        Foo operator+(Foo& other);
        int getNum();

    protected:

    private:
        int num;
};

#endif // FOO_H
```

Foo.cpp

```
Foo::Foo()
{
    num = 0;
}

Foo::Foo(int a)
{
    num = a;
}

Foo Foo::operator+(Foo& other)
{
    Foo tmp = (*this);
    tmp.num += other.num;
    return tmp;
}

int Foo::getNum()
{
    return num;
}
```

The error message says `error: no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'Foo' and 'Foo')` even though the + operator is overloaded for `Foo`-type operands.

Comment: Look at pretty much any example and you will see that the operator overloads take const references. This is not an accident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `(a + a)` yields a prvalue of type `Foo`. The only possible reference parameter types this kind of value can be assigned to are `Foo&&` or `Foo const&`. The reason why `(a + a) + a` (or the equivalent using no brackets) works is the fact that non-const functions can be invoked on prvalues.

I recommend going with the `const` version in this case, but you should also mark the operator `const`:

```
class Foo
{
    ...
    Foo operator+(Foo const& other) const;
};

Foo Foo::operator+(Foo const& other) const
{
    return num + other.num;
}
```

Probably preferrable would be to implement the operator at namespace scope which would allow you to apply the implicit conversion from `int` to `Foo` on both sides of `+`:

```
class Foo
{
    ...
    friend Foo operator+(Foo const& s1, Foo const& s2)
    {
        return s1.num + s2.num;
    }
    ...
};
```

Using this implementation not only

```
Foo c = a + 1;
```

works, but also

```
Foo d = 1 + a;
```

Answer (score 1):

All right, I got it. The only thing that I had to change was to add `const` in Foo.h

```
Foo operator+(const Foo& other);
```

and in Foo.cpp

```
Foo Foo::operator+(const Foo& other)
{
    Foo tmp = (*this);
    tmp.num += other.num;
    return tmp;
}
```

Thanks.